# How can I use an array in str_replace() function?

Tags: php, replace

All I'm trying to do is removing all `<space>` (spaces), `-` (dashes), `,` (commas). Here is my code:-

```
$str = "fwepoki3-4,32de e34d";
$res = str_replace(",", "", str_replace("-", "", str_replace(" ", "", $str)));
```

Is another function in php or any better idea for doing that?

Comment: *"How can I use an array in str_replace() function?"* -- you can use not one, not two, but even three arrays in [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): the `$search`, `$replace` and `$subject` arguments can be arrays. Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) carefully to learn how the array arguments are used.

Comment: If you want to replace invalid characters, you're probably better off using `preg_replace()` with a white-list instead of `str_replace()` with a black-list.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please flag my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that by passing an array as first argument:

```
$res = str_replace(array(' ', '-', ','), '', $str);
```

You can test it here at [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/).

> [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) PHP's function let you choose if the three
>   parameters will be a single value or an array.